# Why are URLs not appearing in References with Bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

**Solution!**

> *Big thank you to CFR! Bibtex is not the best way for a lot of online material. Bibtex was developed before web while Biber particularly for content during the time of web. More about this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211364/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-bibliographies-which-include-a-lot-of-online-sour).*

I cannot spot the error: urls are not appearing with bibtex, why?

[image]

**MWE**

> **MyFile.tex**
>
> ```
> \documentclass[11pt]{article}
>  
> \usepackage{cite}
>  
> \begin{document}
> The Nord Stream \cite{NordStream}.
> Vessels \cite{PohjoinenLaivasto}.
> Gas to the TAP \cite{CIAnaturalGas, EnergyPoliciesReviewEU, TAPoverNabuccoDefeatEU}.
>  
> \bibliographystyle{plain}
> \bibliography{references_henri}{}
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> **references_henri.bib file in Bibtex format(?)**
>
> ```
> @webpage{TAPoverNabuccoDefeatEU,
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 19:59:57 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 20:01:28 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {September 21th, 2014},
>     Month = {July},
>     Title = {TAP Wins on Nabucco: A Total Defeat for the EU},
>     Url = {http://eastbook.eu/en/2013/07/material-en/news-en/tap-wins-on-nabucco-a-total-defeat-for-the-eu/},
>     Year = {2013}}
>  
> @electronic{NordStream,
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 17:47:19 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 18:23:12 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {Nov 11th, 2014},
>     Title = {NordStream's official website},
>     Url = {http://www.nord-stream.com/},
>     Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.nord-stream.com/}}
>  
> @url{CIAnaturalGas,
>     Author = {CIA},
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 19:31:20 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 19:32:46 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {September 13th, 2014},
>     Title = {Country Comparison: Proved Natural Gas Reserves},
>     Url = {https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2253rank.html},
>     Year = {2014}}
>  
> @article{EnergyPoliciesReviewEU,
>     Author = {International Energy Agency},
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 20:42:47 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 20:44:55 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {November 21th, 2014},
>     Pages = {62},
>     Title = {Energy Policies Review: The European Union},
>     Url = {http://www.iea.org/publications/freepublications/publication/eu2008.pdf},
>     Year = {2008}}
>  
> @url{PohjoinenLaivasto,
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 17:53:07 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 17:54:33 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {November 5th, 2014},
>     Title = {Pohjoinen laivasto saa yli 40 alusta},
>     Url = {http://finnish.ruvr.ru/news/2014_04_08/Pohjoinen-laivasto-saa-yli-40-alusta-6885/},
>     Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://finnish.ruvr.ru/news/2014_04_08/Pohjoinen-laivasto-saa-yli-40-alusta-6885/}}
> ```
>
> **Compilation** having no urls
>
> [image]

**Updates**

> I. **Comment to CFR's answer:** using the above MWE and output very bad looking, why?
>
> [image]
>
> II. **Comment to CFR's example 2:** again looking bad, why with my LaTex?
>
> [image]

Comment: With bibtex, don't you need to use a style which explicitly supports urls? (As opposed to if you were using `biblatex`, for example.) In any case, please make your code compilable so that it can be used to reproduce the issue. (I do not have `references_mine.bib` and, if I did, it might not include an entry with the key `someReference`. Take a look at `urlbst` which provides url-ready versions of the standard bibtex styles.

Comment: Judging from the screenshot you've posted, you have entries with types such as `@url`, `@webpage`, and `@electronic`. None of these entry types is recognized by the standard BibTeX bibliography styles. This strongly suggests that you should be using the `biblatex` package (likely with `biber` as the backend) instead of the `plain` bibliography style (with bibtex as the backend).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard BibTeX styles do not support the field `url` or similar. If you need to include urls, you need to use a style which supports them. The `urlbst` package provides a way of converting a BibTeX style file into one which supports such fields. In particular, it provides pre-converted versions of the standard BibTeX styles. For example, `\bibliographystyle{plainurl}` or `plainnat` should give you a version of `plain` with the addition of support for fields like `webpage`, `url` etc.

As Mico noted, you may need to use `biblatex` given the entries in your `.bib` file. A simple example using the sample database provided with the package would be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  \cite{ctan}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In this case, the compilation sequence is (pdf)LaTeX -> biber -> (pdf)LaTeX.

[image: simple bibliography with urls courtesy of <code>biblatex</code>]

## How to modify your MWE

This takes your code and demonstrates how to modify it to use `biblatex`. Some of the entry types you are using are actually unknown even to `biblatex`. (Perhaps they are intended for a specific style?) `@electronic` is known. I've declared `@webpage` and `@url` to be aliases of `@online`, which matches the way `@electronic` entries are handled. This will avoid the need to modify your `.bib` file while hopefully getting the entries handled in an acceptable way.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@webpage{TAPoverNabuccoDefeatEU,
    Date-Added = {2014-11-09 19:59:57 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 20:01:28 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {September 21th, 2014},
    Month = {July},
    Title = {TAP Wins on Nabucco: A Total Defeat for the EU},
    Url = {http://eastbook.eu/en/2013/07/material-en/news-en/tap-wins-on-nabucco-a-total-defeat-for-the-eu/},
    Year = {2013}}

@electronic{NordStream,
    Date-Added = {2014-11-09 17:47:19 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 18:23:12 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {Nov 11th, 2014},
    Title = {NordStream's official website},
    Url = {http://www.nord-stream.com/},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.nord-stream.com/}}

@url{CIAnaturalGas,
    Author = {CIA},
    Date-Added = {2014-11-09 19:31:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 19:32:46 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {September 13th, 2014},
    Title = {Country Comparison: Proved Natural Gas Reserves},
    Url = {https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2253rank.html},
    Year = {2014}}

@article{EnergyPoliciesReviewEU,
    Author = {International Energy Agency},
    Date-Added = {2014-11-09 20:42:47 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 20:44:55 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {November 21th, 2014},
    Pages = {62},
    Title = {Energy Policies Review: The European Union},
    Url = {http://www.iea.org/publications/freepublications/publication/eu2008.pdf},
    Year = {2008}}

@url{PohjoinenLaivasto,
    Date-Added = {2014-11-09 17:53:07 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 17:54:33 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {November 5th, 2014},
    Title = {Pohjoinen laivasto saa yli 40 alusta},
    Url = {http://finnish.ruvr.ru/news/2014_04_08/Pohjoinen-laivasto-saa-yli-40-alusta-6885/},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://finnish.ruvr.ru/news/2014_04_08/Pohjoinen-laivasto-saa-yli-40-alusta-6885/}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{url}{online}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{webpage}{online}

\begin{document}
The Nord Stream \cite{NordStream}.
Vessels \cite{PohjoinenLaivasto}.
Gas to the TAP \cite{CIAnaturalGas, EnergyPoliciesReviewEU, TAPoverNabuccoDefeatEU}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE with <code>biblatex</code>]

Comment: the standard bibtex styles are older than the web

Comment: Another variant of the `plain` bibliography style that's programmed to know what to do with `url` fields is `plainnat`. It can be used with or without the `natbib` package.

Comment: @Mico thanks for reminding me of that. `plainnat` may well be a better choice so I've added that. (I really just picked an example to illustrate the idea.)

Comment: @cfr - In the meantime, I've examined the screenshot the OP posted in more detail, and am starting to suspect that the OP shouldn't be using BibTeX at all, since the bib file appears to contain entries of type `@url`, `@electronic`, and `@webpage`. I suspect he/she really should be using biblatex (which does define these entry types).

Comment: I cannot understand: which packages do I need to import and which lines to add? `\usepackage{urlbst}; \usepacakge{cite}` and `\bibliographystyle{plainurl}`?

Comment: @Mico Good catch. I did not look at the detail of the screen shot and the MWE was not really an MWE...

Comment: @hhh Either `\bibliographystyle{plainurl}` or `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` but if Mico is right, you need to use `biblatex` rather than standard bibtex.

Comment: Just let me know which packages to import: I don't really know the differences between electronic, url and webpage (I use Texpad that does this automatically). I have a lot of websites, articles and their urls as references where I need to specify accessed date and published date. Is biblatex meant for this?

Comment: @hhh `biblatex` supports these entry types, as well as the `url` field in entries such as `article`. `biblatex` is much newer than `bibtex` (the web had been invented in the meanwhile) and offers a lot of flexibility. To use it, you load the `biblatex` package in your preamble. (Don't load `cite`.) Then you add your bibliography, also in the preamble e.g. `\addbibresource{references_mine.bib}`. Then in your document, you write `\printbibliography` to generate the bibliography.

Comment: @hhh If you would provide an MWE, somebody could demonstrate how to do it.

Comment: @cfr provided :)

Comment: @hhh See my edit ;).

Comment: @Mico My version of `biblatex` doesn't know about `@webpage` or `@url`. Do you think declaring them as aliases of `@online` is the appropriate way to handle these? (That's what I've done but you'd indicated `biblatex` knew about them so I'm wondering if you are using a style which might provide the OP with a better solution?)

Comment: I used BibDesk in OSX to generate the `references_henri.bib`, it does not have `online` style thing -- I have no idea which entry online/electronic/etc is the proper way for a reference that is primaly web-based thing, ideas?

Comment: @hhh It is doing some odd things. I just realised that it is using fields `biblatex` doesn't know about by default. Let's see what Mico says. I'm not sure I've offered you a good solution. Normally, for example, you'd use `urldate` for the date of access to a URL. I can modify the code so this is handled correctly but I'm wondering if there's a style which would handle this stuff better out-of-the-box and so offer you a better solution here. [I guess `Lastchecked` is the date you accessed the urls?]

Comment: I think your example code compiles fine even if you omit the two `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` directives. At least, it does compile on my system -- MacTeX2014, all the latest updates installed -- without these two instructions. Maybe biblatex is smart enough to let an unknown entry type default to the catch-all type `@misc`?

Comment: I want to keep the question unedr control and moved the general question about reference tools for web-based material here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211364/which-reference-entry-for-web-based-material-online-electronic-webpage-url, I hope this makes answering easier.

Comment: Incidentally, it's necessary to add an extra pair of curly braces around `{International Energy Agency}`, lest biber (or bibtex) think it's an auther with first name "International", middle name "Energy", and surname "Agency". Since it's a corporate author, it should be sorted under I (for International) rather than A (for Agency), right? :-)

Comment: @Mico Yes, `biblatex` treats unknown types as aliases for `@misc`. However, I wasn't sure if that was as good as treating them as aliases of `@online`.

Comment: I tested your newest example and it looks as bad as earlier, see the update. Any idea why with biblatex? I use TexPad in compiling in OSX.

Comment: @hhh You seem not to have run `biber`? What you are seeing is the `bibkeys` which `biblatex` shows if it cannot resolve the references. Run `biber yourfile` (without the `.tex` extension) and then rerun (pdf)LaTeX.

Comment: @cfr `ERROR - Cannot find control file 'Henri_part.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?`

Comment: @hhh Are you using MacTeX 2014? Recent versions of `biblatex` do not need `backend=biber`. Did you `pdflatex Henri_part.tex` before `biber Henri_part`? Could you try compiling precisely the MWE I posted rather than your original file?

Comment: @cfr I see, I have TexLive2013 -- now downloading [this](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/MacTeX.pkg).

Comment: @hhh TL 2013 should be fine. `biblatex` has used `biber` by default for a long time. Although updating to TL 2014 is not at all a bad idea in general. Did you try compiling my example?

Comment: @cfr I got it compiled after updating to TL 2014! It did not work with TL 2013. I also got it working in TexPad/BibDesk OS X which is super cool, thank you a lot for your help :D

Comment: Looks as if some of this "discussion comments" could be deleted. To me it seems `howpublished` in `@misc` may contain an URL, but `url` inside `@article` or `@manual` (just for example) are ignored. Still `howpublished` doesn't feel right.

Comment: @U.Windl That's style-dependent. If you use Biblatex, `url` is ignored only if you specifically ask for it to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, then use the below format in your `.bib` file:

```
@inproceedings{vqa-url,
    note = {\url{https://visualqa.org}},
}
```

and then, to cite the URL in the LaTeX document, simply do:

```
\cite{vqa-url}
```

which will then give the plain URL as the result in your **references** section:

```
https://visualqa.org
```

and a corresponding number in the actual text section.

Note: Also, there is **no** need to use `\usepackage{url}` in the header section. But, if you want the URL in the references section to be clickable then you MUST use `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the header section of your LaTeX document.

Comment: Please note that if you give an identical answer to multiple questions they all get automatically flagged for moderator attention by the system. It would be better you pick the best suitable question for it and stick with it next time.

Comment: I didn't know about this, thank you for mentioning this Martin :) will keep it in mind.

Comment: I get a "undefined control sequence" for the \url