# What is the best way to handle bibliographies which include a lot of online sources?

Tags: bibliographies, best-practices, online

*This question arises from discussion of [my earlier question about URLs and BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211352/why-are-urls-not-appearing-in-references-with-bibtex), I am looking for a solution that works smoothly with primarily web-based references.*

I have `.bib` files which contain a large number of primarily online sources for which it is essential that information such as the URL, date accessed and date published be included in the bibliography.

**Which tools/packages are best able to handle references to web-based sources, and which entry type(s) should I be using in my `.bib` file?**

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You seem to be conflating at least 2 things. First, there is the issue of the tool-and-package e.g. BibTeX with or without additions such as `natbib` and with whatever style *or* BibLaTeX with Biber (preferably) or BibTeX (if necessary). Second, if you use a `.bib` database file as you would with either of those approaches, there is the question of which entry type is best suited to online sources. But these are different, though connected, questions, and it would be helpful to clarify which interest you. (This is tagged `bibtex` which suggests NOT `biblatex`.)

Comment: I've adjusted the tags to reflect the way I understand your question. Feel free to edit again if I've misunderstood. (You are definitely not interested in cross-referencing, though, and your question has nothing to do with your OS or editor.)

Comment: @cfr I am not qualified enough to assess your comment. I am trying to get some sort of holistic understanding over different methods. I have earlier used `\url{...}` method in references with bibtex, without understanding what is happening. Perhaps you could write an answer explaining different methods?

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question. Feel free to revert my changes if they do not reflect your intentions.

Comment: I answered your comment but you deleted it?

Comment: @cfr yes. It was because my laziness irritated me and I wanted to investigate the issue myself. I found a solution and I wrote an answer how to get Biber working in TexPad/BibDesk OSX. Thank you for encouraging me to get Biber working. Without you, I would still be wasting time with Bibtex and `\url{...}` mess :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BibLaTeX, especially when used with Biber, offers the most powerful and sophisticated handling of bibliographies. It has been designed with web resources in mind from the start and offers extremely nice ways to format a range of resources.

For example:

- all entry types support the `url` and `urldate` fields for specifying URLs and dates accessed;
- all entry types support `doi` and `@article` supports `eid`;
- dedicated `@online` entry type for specifically web-based resources;
- the `eprint`, `eprinttype` and `eprintclass` fields are available which allow much neater, more concise formatting of references for electronic resources e.g. you can use the JSTOR reference rather than giving the full URL and, if `hyperref` is loaded, the information will be hyperlinked automatically;
- you can easily extend the `eprint` facility to cover additional resources.

For example, to add a JSTOR paper, I would use something like this:

```
@article{some-paper,
  author     = ...
  eprint     = {123456789},
  eprinttype = {jstor},
  ...}
```

For resources which are not known to BibLaTeX by default, I extend the `eprint` facility by including additions in a personal `biblatex.cfg`. For example, here is the code I use for `eprinttype` `gutenberg`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:gutenberg}{%
  Project\space Gutenberg\space ebook\addcolon\space
    \ifhyperref
        {\href{http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    \DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:GUTENBERG}{eprint:gutenberg}
```

Then I can use something like this in my `.bib` file:

```
@article{some-ebook,
  author     = ...
  eprint     = {123456789},
  eprinttype = {gutenberg},
  ...}
```

Additional styles may extend these facilities further and styles are generally easier to customise than is the case for BibTeX files. (You don't need to speak `bst` to change things!)

You can also use remote databases directly in some cases and use a wider range of downloadable bibliographical database formats. (You are not restricted to `.bib` files.)

Here is an example based on the sample `.bib` file supplied with `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[sort cites=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  \cite{ctan,kastenholz,baez/article,wilde,baez/online,itzhaki,wassenberg,markey,sigfridsson}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample online resources with BibLaTeX]

To compile:

```
pdflatex <filename>.tex
biber <filename>
pdflatex <filename>.tex
```

You could replace `pdflatex` with `latex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` as required.

Comment: @hhh If you have MacTeX then you have TeX Live which will behave in the same way independent of your OS and editor. I do not know whether TeXPad has buttons or shortcuts to run `biber` or whether you can customise this as I am not familiar with it. So that part I cannot answer. (But I would be surprised if it did not provide an easy way to run `biber`.) But certainly you could produce this result as easily as I can if, for example, you used the command line. [Note that I'm not saying you would need to - I doubt you would. Only that I cannot say for sure about your editor's facilities.]

Comment: Thank you for encouraging +1! Biber works beautifully in TexPad OSX, I made an answer showing all steps in getting it to work [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211383/2956) -- always nice to get encouraged and encourage others to awesome results. This will improve my production time so much! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Biber works so nicely with TexPad OS X and BibDesk and with a lot of online sources.

**Instructions to switch from Bibtex to Biber ([source](https://www.texpadapp.com/support/osx)) in TexPad OSX**

> Typesets and compiles the bibliography file. The underlying bibliography engine is set in the Preferences' window (current options include BibTeX and Biber). Chain: pdfLaTeX  BibTeX/Biber  pdfLaTeX  pdfLaTeX.

[image]

**Examples**

> I think Biber is far better to Bibtex with a lot of online material. I don't need to waste time with the `\url{...}` mess. You can see the result of unmodified *references.bib* file from BibDesk. In the Bibtex case, I should still do manual edits eating productive time to zero. Biber rules!
>
> **Biber**
>
> > [image]
>
> **Bibtex**
>
> [image]

**MWE** working out of the box with MacTex 2014

> ```
> \documentclass[11pt]{article}
> \usepackage{biblatex}
> \usepackage{filecontents}
> \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
> @webpage{TAPoverNabuccoDefeatEU,
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 19:59:57 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 20:01:28 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {September 21th, 2014},
>     Month = {July},
>     Title = {TAP Wins on Nabucco: A Total Defeat for the EU},
>     Url = {http://eastbook.eu/en/2013/07/material-en/news-en/tap-wins-on-nabucco-a-total-defeat-for-the-eu/},
>     Year = {2013}}
>
> @electronic{NordStream,
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 17:47:19 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 18:23:12 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {Nov 11th, 2014},
>     Title = {NordStream's official website},
>     Url = {http://www.nord-stream.com/},
>     Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.nord-stream.com/}}
>
> @article{EnergyPoliciesReviewEU,
>     Author = {International Energy Agency},
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 20:42:47 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 20:44:55 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {November 21th, 2014},
>     Pages = {62},
>     Title = {Energy Policies Review: The European Union},
>     Url = {http://www.iea.org/publications/freepublications/publication/eu2008.pdf},
>     Year = {2008}}
>
> @url{PohjoinenLaivasto,
>     Date-Added = {2014-11-09 17:53:07 +0000},
>     Date-Modified = {2014-11-09 17:54:33 +0000},
>     Lastchecked = {November 5th, 2014},
>     Title = {Pohjoinen laivasto saa yli 40 alusta},
>     Url = {http://finnish.ruvr.ru/news/2014_04_08/Pohjoinen-laivasto-saa-yli-40-alusta-6885/},
>     Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://finnish.ruvr.ru/news/2014_04_08/Pohjoinen-laivasto-saa-yli-40-alusta-6885/}}
> \end{filecontents}
>
> \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
> \begin{document}
>
> \cite{NordStream} and Vessels \cite{PohjoinenLaivasto}.
> Gas to the TAP \cite{EnergyPoliciesReviewEU, TAPoverNabuccoDefeatEU}.
>
> \printbibliography
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: @cfr precisely :D Useful soft landing to all of my friends, collegues and other perfectionists having the irritating problem with a massive number of online content with the best editor I have found so far :)

Answer (score 1):

I am gathering here choices about different methods to reference material properly with urls and other webpage-based material.

**Choices**

> 1. `@misc` entry type and `howpublished=\url{...}` field with Bibtex, instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file)
> 2. BibLatex method as instructed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211354/2956), I haven't been able to get it compiled nicely