# Online sources without "last edited" date field

Tags: biblatex, date

My university requires online sources to include three different dates per entry:

1. Date of original publication
2. Date of last edit
3. date of visiting the website

Well, the first and third date are easy, but what biblatex field corresponds to the second date?

1. `date`
2. **???**
3. `urldate`

In the end, an entry should look something like

> `Uthor, A. (1996): A Stackexchange question. <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask>. (Last edited: 2008-04-36) (Last checked: 2018-01-29)`

where the dates correspond to the above definitions as

1. 1996
2. 2008-04-36
3. 2018-01-29

How do I approach this? Right now, I just use the `note` field, but, of course, this is not exactly desirable, since it is not very "clean".

**EDIT:** just found some other similar questions. I need to work on that, although I have not much knowledge as to which bibmacro I need to edit or, actually, about adding custom fields to entries and incorporating them in macros. I'll see what I can do.

- *[biblatex format for online sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76262)*
- *[What is the best way to handle bibliographies which include a lot of online sources?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211364)*
- *[Biblatex: Custom date fields](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288033)*

I shall investigate them further.

Comment: Are you using `biblatex` as your tagging suggests? Would you be OK with a `biblatex`-specific solution?

Comment: @moewe Yes, I am using `biblatex`. I would indeed. Gosh, you're even faster in seeing this question as I am adding information.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but it might be nice to include an archived version of the page as well. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I don't understand. What page are you referring to?

Comment: The web pages you reference. If they want to know the date accessed, etc... You might as well freeze it on the Internet Archive for posterity.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto now I see. I don't know why they need all those dates, but I just figured it's to get a rough frame of reference of how much a page could have changed since my referencing it. Of course, I __could__ make PDFs of those pages and put them in the annex, but in general, pages are pretty stable and don't change much, so they can still be counter checked for veracity of my referencing their content. Of course, pages that __do__ change their content more often, I should consider freezing. I'll talk to my advisor. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to [Biblatex: Custom date fields](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288033/35864). We need to define a `.dbx` file to make the new `lasteditdate` known to Biber. Then we only need to add a call to `\printlasteditdate` to the URL/URL date macro.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{elk,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {On the Theory of Brontosauruses},
  url          = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.html},
  lasteditdate = {2018-01-15},
  urldate      = {2018-01-29},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{lastedit.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  lasteditdate,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{
  lasteditday,
  lasteditendday,
  lasteditendhour,
  lasteditendminute,
  lasteditendmonth,
  lasteditendsecond,
  lasteditendtimezone,
  lasteditendyear,
  lastedithour,
  lasteditminute,
  lasteditmonth,
  lasteditsecond,
  lastedittimezone,
  lastedityear,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, datamodel=lastedit, lasteditdate=short]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{lastchanged}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  lastchanged = {last changed},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{lasteditdate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{lastchanged}\space#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{lastedityear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printlasteditdate}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Splendid. You know, it makes so much sense when I'm reading it, but I can't even guess how much time it would take me to find out how to do all this on my own. I'll have to check against the documentation and other similar questions to figure out where to get the information myself for future alterations of the same type. +1 for "On the Theory of Brontosauruses" :D

Comment: I get `WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'AsbestosNetwor.2013.ProductsContai' (REF/SiSS_final_report.bib): Invalid field 'lasteditday' for entrytype 'online'` from biber 2.10. Same for `lasteditmonth` and `lastedityear`. I use biber with`--validate_datamodel` and I don't use anything else than `yyyy-mm-dd`. The document compiles as wished, but should I worry about the three warnings per entry?

Comment: @thymaro You don't need to worry, but I have edited the answer so that the warning should be removed. I adapted the code from an earlier answer which was for an older `biblatex` version.

Comment: fyi, it works without warnings on my system, now. thanks again.

Comment: It should be noted that the `.dbx` file @moewe created in the TeX should be named the same as the `datamodel` attribute given to `biblatex`. It will throw the following error (or something alike) when you try to run the `biber %.bcf` command:
```! Package xkeyval Error: `lasteditdate' undefined in families `blx@opt@pre'.```

Hope this saves someone the hour of debugging I just spent on it.